# Does a charge provoke an opportunity attack from the target?

Tags: dnd-4e

If I charge an enemy, when I move adjacent to it do I provoke an OA from him? (the target himself that is)

In my first game in a new group my friends an me are making, we thought that it does not.

I have been thinking about it however, and as it is not a shift, shouldn't it?

If it does, does that mean that a fighter who was a victim of a charge can OA his assailant, stopping his movement, preventing the attack?

As a quick supplement question, It is allowed to make a move then a charge attack. This move would consist of a move action, then a standard action, which is legal correct?

NOTE: this question was answered in the comments below, I have misinterprited the nature of OAs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you charge an enemy you will not provoke an OA attack from him unless he has threatening reach of at least 2 squares where you are moving from one of those squares. The fact that you're approaching him in and of itself doesn't provoke an attack.  It goes off when you are leaving a threatened square.